# How to replace mongodb wt files?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, wiredtiger

I took a backup from my mongodb files located in `/var/lib/mongodb`, and I migrated to a new ubuntu server.

I tried moving my old files in dbpath directory but mongodb stopped working.

How can I add my old `.wt` files in new server without crashing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Hamed, welcome to stackoverflow. It would be helpful if you can check your mongod log and post the specific error(s) that you are getting when you attempt to start mongod. It's hard to guess without seeing more information. It could be something simple like the permissions are incorrect, or it could be that you're missing files or the database files are not in a consistent state. Did you stop your old server before you moved/copied the files?

Comment: @helmy I stopped my server , then replaced .wt files, But it seemed like my last server mongo version was 3.6 and the new server was 3.2 . I took a mongodump from my collection this morning and restored with mongostore and it solved actually :D .